# Discrete to continuous transfer functions discrepancy

Tags: transfer-function

in the attempt of implementing a discrete time version of a transfer function I realized that the continuous and discrete versions behave very differently.
Here is the tf in the s domain:

```
     0.981 s^2 + 11.32 s + 7.44e+004
Cs = --------------------------------
     5.051e+010 s^2 + 5.828e+011 s
```

using the Octave command:

```
c2d(Cs,0.002,'tustin')
```

I get this:

```
      2.088e-011 z^2 - 3.549e-011 z + 2.044e-011
Cz = ----------------------------------------
      z^2 - 1.977 z + 0.9772
```

The response to the same sinusoidal input looks like this:

[image]

I cannot explain why this is happening. Can anybody clarify it?

Thank you very much,
Guido

Ps: the commands I used are:

```
Gs_num = [5.0506e+010, 5.8276e+011]
Gs_den = [1.5612e-001, 1.8014e+000, 1.1841e+004]
w_c = 1*2*pi
Cs = tf(w_c, [1 0])*Gs^-1
Cz=c2d(Cs, 0.002, 'tustin')
```

And then simulink screenshot

[image]